# OpenCV warp perspective to align and equalize rectangle size

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to align two rectangles using the perspectiveTransform. In the image below there are the two orange rectangles (I know their dimensions and locations) and I want to warp the perspective so that they are of approximately the same size and in line (the green ones in the image). A perspectiveTransform that e.g. makes the small one equal in size with the big one doesn't really do the trick, as the size of the big one changes too. Any help much appreciated!

[image: Rectangle alignment]

Comment: You need a transformation that works for both rectangles together, or just one at a time?

Comment: I think both together - they are in a single image.